# Run two different PHP programs at the same time

Tags: php

Good afternoon!

I'm currently working on a small project. I try to make a simple REST api in PHP to control music. The idea is that a call to the api executes a server command with the `exec` function of PHP.
This is already working :)

What I like to do know is to play multiple files after each other, like a playlist. My idea is two different programs.
One program that manage a queue with files that must be played and a program that plays the first item in the queue, than the second, etc.
While the song is playing the queue should be modified.

So may question is: is this even possible? I there a way to run these programs at the same time? Or is my way of thinking way to complex and is there a much better and simpler solution?

Thanks for thinking along with me :)
Niels

Comment: How are you playing the song?

Comment: Please consider showing us some code, so we have an idea what you did already.

Comment: maybe two different functions?

Comment: I'm playing the song with a library called mplayer. The code now is not very relevant. It is just a api that executes a command. That's it

Answer (score 0):

You could :

1. Make 2 different API calls from your client, 1 for your queue and 1 for your player
2. Create a bash script that launches both processes as daemon using the `&` char, and make your API call this script
3. Trying some async threads in PHP (I did not test yet), doc [here](http://php.net/pthreads) and [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.thread.php)

Comment: My ultimate target is to run the playlist on serverlevel. With the first option that is not possible if think so?

Second and third option are good idea. I don't have much experience with bash processes. I think I will take a look at the threads in PHP. Thanks :)

Comment: I think it is possible, if you have 2 API routes, for ex /start/playlist and /start/player, each function make a `exec` command. You can call both routes asynchronously from your client (Javascript for ex)